# Scan Ble Packet transmitted by iOS device in background

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am developing an application in which iOS device is advertising BLE Packet and android device is scanning, this is working perfectly if iOS device is in foreground but if iOS device is in background then I am receiving blank Ble Packet in androrid. My Question is how I can scan complete BLE packet when iOS device is in background ?

Comment: Refer to the discussion [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising) - Only other iOS devices that are specifically scanning for the advertised service can discover a service advertised by iOS in the background

Comment: Thanks, I read the docs according to them I can't do this because they are not advertising that thing in background.

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there any other way by which I can do this?